# C# get system network usage

Tags: c#, networking

I need a way to get the current system network usage, up and down.

I found some on the net but they're not working out for me.

Thanks for your help

Code snippet:

```
 private void timerPerf_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
                return;

            NetworkInterface[] interfaces
                = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();

            foreach (NetworkInterface ni in interfaces)
            {
                this.labelnetup.Text = "    Bytes Sent: " + ni.GetIPv4Statistics().BytesSent;
                this.labelnetdown.Text = "    Bytes Rec: " + ni.GetIPv4Statistics().BytesReceived;
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Please see [Report information from NetworkInterface: network statistics](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0580__Network/ReportinformationfromNetworkInterfacenetworkstatistics.htm) for a good sample program:

```
using System;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;

class MainClass
{
    static void Main()
    {
        if (!NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
           return;

        NetworkInterface[] interfaces 
            = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();

        foreach (NetworkInterface ni in interfaces)
        {                
            Console.WriteLine("    Bytes Sent: {0}", 
                ni.GetIPv4Statistics().BytesSent);
            Console.WriteLine("    Bytes Received: {0}",
                ni.GetIPv4Statistics().BytesReceived);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the snippet, how can this be done inside a Windows Form, with a timer.

I have posted a snippet with your code in my question

Comment: No it's returning 0 all the time, and I try to set a download but no changes in the numbers.

Answer (score 7):

You can get the current system's network usage by working with PerformanceCounterCategory too:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        PerformanceCounterCategory pcg = new PerformanceCounterCategory("Network Interface");
        string instance = pcg.GetInstanceNames()[0];
        PerformanceCounter pcsent = new PerformanceCounter("Network Interface", "Bytes Sent/sec", instance);
        PerformanceCounter pcreceived = new PerformanceCounter("Network Interface", "Bytes Received/sec", instance);

        Console.WriteLine("Bytes Sent: {0}", pcsent.NextValue() / 1024);
        Console.WriteLine("Bytes Received: {0}", pcreceived.NextValue() / 1024);
    }
}
```

Source: http://dotnet-snippets.com/snippet/show-network-traffic-sent-and-received/580

Comment: it is speed, not actual bytes

Comment: Two points to take in mind when using this answer: 1) `pcg.GetInstanceNames()` holds all network interfaces so one should filter the one he is interest in (`Ethernet` for example)... 2) the first time you call `pcsent.NextValue()` will always return `0.0`, per MSDN documentation you should wait at least 1 seconds before calling this function again to get some real value. See also: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21420207/why-does-this-performance-counter-always-return-zero)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code for a windows form with timer.

```
Imports System.Net.NetworkInformation
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Namespace InterfaceTrafficWatch
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Network Interface Traffic Watch
    ''' by Mohamed Mansour
    ''' 
    ''' Free to use under GPL open source license!
    ''' </summary>
    Partial Public Class MainForm
        Inherits Form
        ''' <summary>
        ''' Timer Update (every 1 sec)
        ''' </summary>
        Private Const timerUpdate As Double = 1000

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Interface Storage
        ''' </summary>
        Private nicArr As NetworkInterface()

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Main Timer Object 
        ''' (we could use something more efficient such 
        ''' as interop calls to HighPerformanceTimers)
        ''' </summary>
        Private timer As Timer

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Constructor
        ''' </summary>
        Public Sub New()
            InitializeComponent()
            InitializeNetworkInterface()
            InitializeTimer()
        End Sub

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Initialize all network interfaces on this computer
        ''' </summary>
        Private Sub InitializeNetworkInterface()
            ' Grab all local interfaces to this computer
            nicArr = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()

            ' Add each interface name to the combo box
            For i As Integer = 0 To nicArr.Length - 1
                cmbInterface.Items.Add(nicArr(i).Name)
            Next

            ' Change the initial selection to the first interface
            cmbInterface.SelectedIndex = 0
        End Sub

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Initialize the Timer
        ''' </summary>
        Private Sub InitializeTimer()
            timer = New Timer()
            timer.Interval = CInt(timerUpdate)
            AddHandler timer.Tick, New EventHandler(AddressOf timer_Tick)
            'timer.Tick += New EventHandler(AddressOf timer_Tick)
            timer.Start()
        End Sub


        ''' <summary>
        ''' Update GUI components for the network interfaces
        ''' </summary>
        Private Sub UpdateNetworkInterface()

            ' Grab NetworkInterface object that describes the current interface
            Dim nic As NetworkInterface = nicArr(cmbInterface.SelectedIndex)

            ' Grab the stats for that interface
            Dim interfaceStats As IPv4InterfaceStatistics = nic.GetIPv4Statistics()

            Dim BS As Double = CDbl(lblBytesSent.Text) * 1024 * 1024
            Dim bytesSentSpeed As Double = (interfaceStats.BytesSent - BS) / 1024

            Dim BR As Double = CDbl(lblBytesReceived.Text) * 1024 * 1024
            Dim bytesReceivedSpeed As Double = (interfaceStats.BytesReceived - BR) / 1024

            ' Update the labels
            lblSpeed.Text = CInt(((nic.Speed) / 1024) / 1024).ToString() + " Mbs"

            lblInterfaceType.Text = nic.NetworkInterfaceType.ToString()
            'lblSpeed.Text = nic.Speed.ToString()
            lblBytesReceived.Text = ((CInt(interfaceStats.BytesReceived / 1024) / 1024)).ToString()
            lblBytesSent.Text = ((CInt(interfaceStats.BytesSent.ToString() / 1024) / 1024)).ToString()
            lblTimeStamp.Text = Date.Now().ToString()
            lblDescription.Text = nic.Description.ToString()
            lblPhyAddorMAC.Text = nic.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString()
            lblName.Text = nic.Name.ToString()

            lblIPStatistics.Text = nic.Id.ToString()
            lblUpload.Text = bytesSentSpeed.ToString() + " KB/s"
            lblDownload.Text = bytesReceivedSpeed.ToString() + " KB/s"

        End Sub

        ''' <summary>
        ''' The Timer event for each Tick (second) to update the UI
        ''' </summary>
        ''' <param name="sender"></param>
        ''' <param name="e"></param>
        Private Sub timer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
            UpdateNetworkInterface()
        End Sub


        Friend WithEvents cmbInterface As System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
        Friend WithEvents lblSpeed As System.Windows.Forms.Label
        Friend WithEvents lblInterfaceType As System.Windows.Forms.Label
        Friend WithEvents lblBytesReceived As System.Windows.Forms.Label
        Friend WithEvents lblBytesSent As System.Windows.Forms.Label
        Friend WithEvents lblUpload As System.Windows.Forms.Label
        Friend WithEvents Timer1 As System.Windows.Forms.Timer
        Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

        Private Sub InitializeComponent()
            Me.components = New System.ComponentModel.Container()
            Me.cmbInterface = New System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox()
            Me.lblSpeed = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
            Me.lblInterfaceType = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
            Me.lblBytesReceived = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
            Me.lblBytesSent = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
            Me.lblUpload = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
            Me.Timer1 = New System.Windows.Forms.Timer(Me.components)
            Me.lblDownload = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
            Me.Label1 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
            Me.Label2 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
            Me.Label3 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
            Me.Label4 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
            Me.Label5 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
            Me.Label6 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
            Me.lblTimeStamp = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
            Me.Label8 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
            Me.lblDescription = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
            Me.Label9 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
            Me.lblPhyAddorMAC = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
            Me.Label10 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
            Me.lblName = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
            Me.Label11 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
            Me.lblIPStatistics = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
            Me.Label13 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
            Me.Label7 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
            Me.Label12 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
            Me.Label14 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
            Me.SuspendLayout()
            '
            'cmbInterface
            '
            Me.cmbInterface.FormattingEnabled = True
            Me.cmbInterface.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(139, 24)
            Me.cmbInterface.Name = "cmbInterface"
            Me.cmbInterface.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(232, 21)
            Me.cmbInterface.TabIndex = 0
            '
            'lblSpeed
            '
            Me.lblSpeed.AutoSize = True
            Me.lblSpeed.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(136, 60)
            Me.lblSpeed.Name = "lblSpeed"
            Me.lblSpeed.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(13, 13)
            Me.lblSpeed.TabIndex = 1
            Me.lblSpeed.Text = "0"
            '
            'lblInterfaceType
            '
            Me.lblInterfaceType.AutoSize = True
            Me.lblInterfaceType.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(136, 84)
            Me.lblInterfaceType.Name = "lblInterfaceType"
            Me.lblInterfaceType.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(13, 13)
            Me.lblInterfaceType.TabIndex = 1
            Me.lblInterfaceType.Text = "0"
            '
            'lblBytesReceived
            '
            Me.lblBytesReceived.AutoSize = True
            Me.lblBytesReceived.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(136, 112)
            Me.lblBytesReceived.Name = "lblBytesReceived"
            Me.lblBytesReceived.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(13, 13)
            Me.lblBytesReceived.TabIndex = 1
            Me.lblBytesReceived.Text = "0"
            '
            'lblBytesSent
            '
            Me.lblBytesSent.AutoSize = True
            Me.lblBytesSent.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(136, 142)
            Me.lblBytesSent.Name = "lblBytesSent"
            Me.lblBytesSent.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(13, 13)
            Me.lblBytesSent.TabIndex = 1
            Me.lblBytesSent.Text = "0"
            '
            'lblUpload
            '
            Me.lblUpload.AutoSize = True
            Me.lblUpload.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(136, 175)
            Me.lblUpload.Name = "lblUpload"
            Me.lblUpload.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(13, 13)
            Me.lblUpload.TabIndex = 1
            Me.lblUpload.Text = "0"
            '
            'lblDownload
            '
            Me.lblDownload.AutoSize = True
            Me.lblDownload.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(136, 202)
            Me.lblDownload.Name = "lblDownload"
            Me.lblDownload.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(13, 13)
            Me.lblDownload.TabIndex = 1
            Me.lblDownload.Text = "0"
            '
            'Label1
            '
            Me.Label1.AutoSize = True
            Me.Label1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(12, 60)
            Me.Label1.Name = "Label1"
            Me.Label1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(38, 13)
            Me.Label1.TabIndex = 1
            Me.Label1.Text = "Speed"
            '
            'Label2
            '
            Me.Label2.AutoSize = True
            Me.Label2.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(12, 84)
            Me.Label2.Name = "Label2"
            Me.Label2.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(73, 13)
            Me.Label2.TabIndex = 1
            Me.Label2.Text = "InterfaceType"
            '
            'Label3
            '
            Me.Label3.AutoSize = True
            Me.Label3.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(12, 112)
            Me.Label3.Name = "Label3"
            Me.Label3.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(82, 13)
            Me.Label3.TabIndex = 1
            Me.Label3.Text = "Bytes Received"
            '
            'Label4
            '
            Me.Label4.AutoSize = True
            Me.Label4.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(12, 142)
            Me.Label4.Name = "Label4"
            Me.Label4.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(58, 13)
            Me.Label4.TabIndex = 1
            Me.Label4.Text = "Bytes Sent"
            '
            'Label5
            '
            Me.Label5.AutoSize = True
            Me.Label5.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(12, 175)
            Me.Label5.Name = "Label5"
            Me.Label5.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(73, 13)
            Me.Label5.TabIndex = 1
            Me.Label5.Text = "Upload speed"
            '
            'Label6
            '
            Me.Label6.AutoSize = True
            Me.Label6.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(12, 202)
            Me.Label6.Name = "Label6"
            Me.Label6.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(87, 13)
            Me.Label6.TabIndex = 1
            Me.Label6.Text = "Download speed"
            '
            'lblTimeStamp
            '
            Me.lblTimeStamp.AutoSize = True
            Me.lblTimeStamp.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(116, 369)
            Me.lblTimeStamp.Name = "lblTimeStamp"
            Me.lblTimeStamp.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(13, 13)
            Me.lblTimeStamp.TabIndex = 1
            Me.lblTimeStamp.Text = "0"
            '
            'Label8
            '
            Me.Label8.AutoSize = True
            Me.Label8.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(17, 369)
            Me.Label8.Name = "Label8"
            Me.Label8.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(60, 13)
            Me.Label8.TabIndex = 1
            Me.Label8.Text = "TimeStamp"
            '
            'lblDescription
            '
            Me.lblDescription.AutoSize = True
            Me.lblDescription.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(136, 232)
            Me.lblDescription.Name = "lblDescription"
            Me.lblDescription.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(13, 13)
            Me.lblDescription.TabIndex = 1
            Me.lblDescription.Text = "0"
            '
            'Label9
            '
            Me.Label9.AutoSize = True
            Me.Label9.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(12, 232)
            Me.Label9.Name = "Label9"
            Me.Label9.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(60, 13)
            Me.Label9.TabIndex = 1
            Me.Label9.Text = "Description"
            '
            'lblPhyAddorMAC
            '
            Me.lblPhyAddorMAC.AutoSize = True
            Me.lblPhyAddorMAC.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(136, 259)
            Me.lblPhyAddorMAC.Name = "lblPhyAddorMAC"
            Me.lblPhyAddorMAC.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(13, 13)
            Me.lblPhyAddorMAC.TabIndex = 1
            Me.lblPhyAddorMAC.Text = "0"
            '
            'Label10
            '
            Me.Label10.AutoSize = True
            Me.Label10.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(12, 259)
            Me.Label10.Name = "Label10"
            Me.Label10.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(82, 13)
            Me.Label10.TabIndex = 1
            Me.Label10.Text = "PhyAdd or MAC"
            '
            'lblName
            '
            Me.lblName.AutoSize = True
            Me.lblName.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(136, 288)
            Me.lblName.Name = "lblName"
            Me.lblName.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(13, 13)
            Me.lblName.TabIndex = 1
            Me.lblName.Text = "0"
            '
            'Label11
            '
            Me.Label11.AutoSize = True
            Me.Label11.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(12, 288)
            Me.Label11.Name = "Label11"
            Me.Label11.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(35, 13)
            Me.Label11.TabIndex = 1
            Me.Label11.Text = "Name"
            '
            'lblIPStatistics
            '
            Me.lblIPStatistics.AutoSize = True
            Me.lblIPStatistics.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(136, 312)
            Me.lblIPStatistics.Name = "lblIPStatistics"
            Me.lblIPStatistics.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(13, 13)
            Me.lblIPStatistics.TabIndex = 1
            Me.lblIPStatistics.Text = "0"
            '
            'Label13
            '
            Me.Label13.AutoSize = True
            Me.Label13.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(12, 312)
            Me.Label13.Name = "Label13"
            Me.Label13.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(39, 13)
            Me.Label13.TabIndex = 1
            Me.Label13.Text = "NIC ID"
            '
            'Label7
            '
            Me.Label7.AutoSize = True
            Me.Label7.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(9, 32)
            Me.Label7.Name = "Label7"
            Me.Label7.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(30, 13)
            Me.Label7.TabIndex = 1
            Me.Label7.Text = "NICs"
            '
            'Label12
            '
            Me.Label12.AutoSize = True
            Me.Label12.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(321, 112)
            Me.Label12.Name = "Label12"
            Me.Label12.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(23, 13)
            Me.Label12.TabIndex = 1
            Me.Label12.Text = "MB"
            '
            'Label14
            '
            Me.Label14.AutoSize = True
            Me.Label14.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(321, 142)
            Me.Label14.Name = "Label14"
            Me.Label14.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(23, 13)
            Me.Label14.TabIndex = 1
            Me.Label14.Text = "MB"
            '
            'MainForm
            '
            Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(660, 422)
            Me.Controls.Add(Me.Label13)
            Me.Controls.Add(Me.lblIPStatistics)
            Me.Controls.Add(Me.Label11)
            Me.Controls.Add(Me.lblName)
            Me.Controls.Add(Me.Label10)
            Me.Controls.Add(Me.lblPhyAddorMAC)
            Me.Controls.Add(Me.Label9)
            Me.Controls.Add(Me.lblDescription)
            Me.Controls.Add(Me.Label8)
            Me.Controls.Add(Me.lblTimeStamp)
            Me.Controls.Add(Me.Label6)
            Me.Controls.Add(Me.lblDownload)
            Me.Controls.Add(Me.Label5)
            Me.Controls.Add(Me.lblUpload)
            Me.Controls.Add(Me.Label4)
            Me.Controls.Add(Me.lblBytesSent)
            Me.Controls.Add(Me.Label3)
            Me.Controls.Add(Me.Label2)
            Me.Controls.Add(Me.Label14)
            Me.Controls.Add(Me.Label12)
            Me.Controls.Add(Me.lblBytesReceived)
            Me.Controls.Add(Me.Label7)
            Me.Controls.Add(Me.Label1)
            Me.Controls.Add(Me.lblInterfaceType)
            Me.Controls.Add(Me.lblSpeed)
            Me.Controls.Add(Me.cmbInterface)
            Me.Name = "MainForm"
            Me.Text = "Band Width Statistics"
            Me.ResumeLayout(False)
            Me.PerformLayout()

        End Sub
        Friend WithEvents lblDownload As System.Windows.Forms.Label
        Friend WithEvents Label1 As System.Windows.Forms.Label
        Friend WithEvents Label2 As System.Windows.Forms.Label
        Friend WithEvents Label3 As System.Windows.Forms.Label
        Friend WithEvents Label4 As System.Windows.Forms.Label
        Friend WithEvents Label5 As System.Windows.Forms.Label
        Friend WithEvents Label6 As System.Windows.Forms.Label
        Friend WithEvents lblTimeStamp As System.Windows.Forms.Label
        Friend WithEvents Label8 As System.Windows.Forms.Label
        Friend WithEvents lblDescription As System.Windows.Forms.Label
        Friend WithEvents Label9 As System.Windows.Forms.Label
        Friend WithEvents lblPhyAddorMAC As System.Windows.Forms.Label
        Friend WithEvents Label10 As System.Windows.Forms.Label
        Friend WithEvents lblName As System.Windows.Forms.Label
        Friend WithEvents Label11 As System.Windows.Forms.Label
        Friend WithEvents lblIPStatistics As System.Windows.Forms.Label
        Friend WithEvents Label13 As System.Windows.Forms.Label
        Friend WithEvents Label7 As System.Windows.Forms.Label
        Friend WithEvents Label12 As System.Windows.Forms.Label
        Friend WithEvents Label14 As System.Windows.Forms.Label
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add another answer because I assume I am not the only one who would like to determine the badnwith in MBit/s rather than just bytes:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Measures the bitrate in Mbits for one secund and calculates the MBits
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="networkCard">The networkinterface you want the usage of</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static double GetNetworkUtilization(NetworkInterface networkCard)
    {
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();//used to stop the time from strating to measure till the end
        sw.Start();
        var startSent = networkCard.GetIPStatistics().BytesSent;//gets all bytes sent and received since boot
        var startRecv = networkCard.GetIPStatistics().BytesReceived;
        Thread.Sleep(1000);//waits for a secund (if you choose smaller values the result will fluctuate a lot due to network spikes)
        sw.Stop();//stops the measurement
        var bytes_sent = (networkCard.GetIPStatistics().BytesSent - startSent); //gets all bytes sent and received since boot again and remose the initialliy sent byts
        var bytes_received = (networkCard.GetIPStatistics().BytesReceived - startRecv);
        var bytes_total = bytes_sent + bytes_received;//the sum is the number of bytes sent during the measurment of one second
        double mbits = (double)bytes_total * 8 / 1000000 / (((double)sw.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000));//we now convert bits to bytes and mSec to Sec
        return mbits; //and return the value
    }
```

this function should be called from a thread to not block the GUI for a second