Getting correct network usage statistics from cmd, powershell or C#
I need to monitor total bytes sent and total bytes received on a Windows Server machine and I need to automate this for tracking the trend and visual presentation. Currently I am using C# very similar to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2081844/5033397
However the results are totally off, they do not match the stats that I see in perfmon at all (task manager -> performance tab -> open performance monitor on the bottom). The C# approach gives me 60 MBytes/s while in perfmon I can see total traffic to be around 1.5 Gbits/s. I also tried typeperf "\Network Interface(*)\Bytes Total/sec" which gives the same results as the C# approach.
Is there any way to get the "real" total bytes per second on a Windows machine using cmd, powershell or C#?

The standard powershell solution would be:
Get-Counter -Counter "\Network Interface(*)\Bytes Total/sec"

Though I don't think this will give a massively different answer.
Some discussion on this I found:
Why it underreports
I also found this c# solution that might be helpful:
Csharp Example

The referenced powershell call gives me more-less the same (inaccurate) results as typeperf.

@andy250 I imagined it would be as so, as it gathers roughly the same information.
Try all the examples in: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.diagnostics/get-counter?view=powershell-7.4
And see if any of them are closer to your desired output maybe
